How to convert .grd file extension to .tif in MAC OS
I am trying to convert .grd file from here (on the left sided panle, Gridded Data Real Time > Daily Maximum Temp (1 * 1) Binary). While there is an existing library called IMDLib to read and convert .grd file to .tif, the problem is when I download it via the python library, the spatial resolution is .5 * .5. Now, since I'm trying to calculate anomaly, the historical data for 30 years is in 1 * 1 spatial resolution. I just want to convert the .grd to .tiff. How do I do it?

Can you give more precise details of what .grd file you have downloaded, because that page is a sea of menus and links. Its a badly designed web page where the URL doesn't change as you navigate, so you'll have to tell us what to click on. You should also link to this conversion program.

So, in the left sided panel, if you navigate to "Gridded Data Real Time" and then "Daily Maximum Temp (1 * 1) Binary option.

This data can be downloaded via a direct link (eg https://www.imdpune.gov.in/cmpg/Realtimedata/maxone/maxone.php?maxone=06052024) and returns a binary file of just the data values, which I save as max1_06052024.grd. It is 3844 bytes long which is 31x31x4. So it looks like a 31x31 grid of 4-byte values.
There's also a link to a control file which gives us some clues to the file format:
DSET f:\T\DAILY\DAILY_1.0\UPLOADING_1.0\MAX_1.0\max1_18072019.GRD               
TITLE 1.0 DEGREE ANALYZED GRIDS
UNDEF  99.9
XDEF  31  LINEAR 67.5 1.0
YDEF  31  LINEAR 7.5 1.0
ZDEF    1  LINEAR 1 1 
TDEF   1  LINEAR JUN2006 1DY
VARS  1
Tmax 0 99 TACTUAL
ENDVARS

This lets me construct a header file for GDAL to read it, so I create a header file called max1_06052024.hdr:
BANDS: 1
COLS: 31
ROWS: 31
DATATYPE: F32
BYTE_ORDER: LSB
UL_X_COORDINATE: 67.5
UL_Y_COORDINATE: 7.5
LR_X_COORDINATE: 97.5
LR_Y_COORDINATE: 37.5

These values are partly trial and error, but result in a grid with 1.0 unit spacing. I'm not totally sure if the coordinates are cell centres or cell edges, and the supplied control file doesn't say. But we proceed...
Then use the gdal translate command line tool (available on all platforms with the GDAL utilities) to convert to GeoTIFF:
$ gdal_translate max1_06052024.grd max1_06052024.tiff
Input file size is 31, 31
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

Which I can then read in using standard GDAL-compliant tools and plot, and it looks to be in the right place.

(although it might be half a cell out, do check before any detailed work).
So you have to construct a matching .hdr file for every .grd file you use, and then you can either process it through gdal_translate to make a GeoTIFF, or if you are using GDAL compatible tools anyway you don't need the translate step, since the .grd and .hdr files make a GDAL compatible raster data set anyway.
You've not said what you want to do with the data once you have it in TIFF format so this should be sufficient information anwyay.

I got the gdal translate part as I know GDAL but how to do I make a .hdr file out of the .grd file? I'm looking for links but couldn't find any.

Use a text editor (the Mac one seems to be "TextEdit" but idk), type it in (or copy paste from here), save as {whatever the grid filename is}.hdr in the same folder as the .grd file.
